# swap butterfly trade

Tags: swaps, forward-start, butterfly

for example 2-5-10 year butterfly trade. Butterfly can be constructed via spot swap trades?
I am wondering if it make sense to construct it via forward starting swap trades ? i.e., constructing it from 3 year forward starting 2Y swap and a 5 year forward starting 5 year swap? what are the considerations?

Comment: Let's say we pay 40k of 2s5s10s: i.e. +40k 5y vs -20k for 2s and 10s. To replicate this via fwds u'd do something like: rec 5y5y in 15k vs pay 2y3y in 15k (so u r duration flat). The resulting profile is: -10k in 2y, +25k+15k=+40k in 5y and -30k in 10y.  So u end up with the fly profile you're after plus some 2s10s flattener. So in addition to the 2y3y and 5y5y fwds, you'll need a 2s10s steepener. Conclusion: just trading the leveraged fwds won't replicate a spot starting butterfly, there will always be a residual curve position (this follows from the nature of what fwd swaps are).

Comment: Curious why you may want to do this ? Unless you don't want your original trade to be recognised?

Comment: Imo, generally the reason to trade fwd starting flies is rv or favourable rd&c. Unless you are hedging some bespoke risk very specifically, there would be no reason to do something like this.. unless ofcourse you just like paying bid/offer, brokerage..in which case pls dm me.